# python error in get trending topic using tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to get top 20 trending topic through twitter api based on the Tweepy library.

Here is my python code:

```
import tweepy
import json
import time

today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""

ACCESS_KEY = ""
ACCESS_SECRET = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

trends = api.trends_daily(today)
print trends
```

I am using trends_daily function to get the top 20 trending topics for each day.

The variable "today" is in **date format**:  `today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`. And I tried string format as well. However, it keeps report error message:

```
File "/Users/Ivy/PycharmProjects/TwitterTrend/trends.py", line 17, in <module>
    trends = api.trends_daily("2014-06-03")
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 230, in _call
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 203, in execute
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're using tweepy version 1 which is [no longer supported](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/daily): https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/daily.json

Try to re-install (version 1.1), for example:
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json

Comment: thanks! got it, and is it possible to get 20 trending topics now, i see the api doc, can only get 10

Comment: Nope, it seems that Tweeter restricts to 10 results and recommends not to re-send the same request in a frequency of less than 1 per 5 minutes as the result is cached and won't change as well as it might "blacklist" your IP as a potential attacker...